# Dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Debian 8.4

Tags: dual-boot, debian

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Debian, I get no boot option for Ubuntu. How can I fix the boot menu?

Answer (score 2):

Grub Menu will appear if you press and hold

> Shift

during loading Grub, then select the distro you want to boot into.

More info [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring%20GRUB%202)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the question, I suspect "no boot option for Ubuntu" refers to GRUB 2 boot loader that has been installed earlier by Debian, and not the one belongs to Ubuntu.

In related matter, I have a dual boot setup of Debian 8.2 Xfce and Xubuntu 14.04 on my test machine. For my setup, the installations are noted below.

- Debian is installed first, then Xubuntu is installed afterwards
- Boot loader that is installed to hard disk itself i.e. `/dev/sda` belongs to Debian, which will not detect Xubuntu that was installed afterwards
- Boot loader that is installed to its partition i.e. `/dev/sda3` belongs to Xubuntu, which will detect Debian at partition `/dev/sda2`, when chainloading from boot loader at `/dev/sda`.

Following this, I'd say "no boot option for Ubuntu" occurs because GRUB 2 boot loader in Debian somehow doesn't detect other operating systems that have been installed afterwards. Yet, I didn't manage to reconfigure GRUB 2 configurations in Debian to make detection possible.

### Workaround

The workaround is to add new entry manually in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, then run `update-grub` in Debian. Despite shown for Xubuntu, this can adapted similarly for Ubuntu.

```
menuentry "Chainload to Xubuntu" {
    insmod ext2
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set <UUID>
    chainloader +1
}
```

`<UUID>` is UUID value of the partition that can be checked by running `blkid` as root in Debian. Look for the corresponding line that looks like `/dev/sda3: UUID="..."` and copy the value without the quotes (your Ubuntu might be installed at different partition).

`chainloader +1` will look for bootloader in next partition. Chainloading is more convenient than specifying `linux` and `initrd` manually, because user doesn't have to edit these lines whenever Ubuntu had updated its kernel release.

Anyway, when the menu is selected, the GRUB 2 boot loader will redirect to another GRUB 2 boot loader that belongs to Xubuntu, which will show boot option for Xubuntu.

### Solution found (2016-06-06)

There was no need to reconfigure GRUB 2 configuration at all. The relevant configuration file already exists at `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`. Unlike Ubuntu and its flavours, Debian by default is missing a package called `os-prober`.

Therefore, Debian users will have to manually install `os-prober` via APT and re-run `update-grub`. Boot options for Ubuntu will be seen on next boot.

See also [this answer on Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286082), which has been posted recently from this date.

Comment: Instead of `chainloader` I would use `multiboot`. It's simpler and can even work when dual booting multiple distributions from the same partition. Something along the lines of `menuentry 'Ubuntu' {
        multiboot (hd1,1)/boot/grub/core.img
}` could work.