# run 2 ubuntu releases from 1 harddisk

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, upgrade

Regarding closed question '831777/ubuntu-16-04-vs-ubuntu-16-10' I would like to ask Duncan how to 'Grub' this setup. I would like to reorganize my system in the way that Duncan suggests but am not sure how to use grub in a consistent manner. On some moment in time I think you have to stop using grub from one partition and start using it from another partition. On this moment I am using Grub-customizer on a multidisk-multiUbuntu system and I recently had unexplainable boot-problems that I would like to avoid in the future,
Thanks

Comment: You should be able to just install to a new partition, tell the installer to install to a separate partition, and to _not_  install the bootloader. Then you can just run Grub customizer again to pick up the new install and add it to the list.

Comment: I prefer to not use grub customizer. It likes to create its own edited versions of grub files. Ok for some simple edits of configuration files, but they are simple if willing to manual edit a file. You have to decide which install is your main working install and keep its grub as default boot whether UEFI or BIOS. http://askubuntu.com/questions/838450/how-can-ubiquity-be-forced-not-to-install-grub/838527#838527 I mostly do something similar to this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Comment: Thanks JonasCz and oldfred,  problem solved. How can I close my question, could not find  that 'button' somewhere