# Installing Ubuntu without Grub 'ubiquity --no -bootloader'

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, bootloader

First off, no Windows is involved, and no, it's not UEFI.
I have 6 different flavors of Linux running on this old laptop, one of those distros is the only one I trust to manage the bootloader, I don't need a new bootloader I'll go in an add Ubuntu manually after install.

Calamares is an awesome installer that gives you the choice to not install a bootloader, that appears to be absent in the Ubuntu installer, I looked everywhere, but I couldn't find it. Surely you can install Ubuntu without a bootloader. No, I'm not going to back up the MBR and reinstall it etc.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a proper linux way to start the installer with a command line that does this?
2. Or, until a fix is available, should I just install the darn thing in the Ubuntu partition?

Comment: Lubuntu uses Calamares (after 18.04 anyway), and uses more than just `ubiquity` & `calamares` too. Ubuntu allows the use of `lilo` as a boot-loader, and yes installing without `grub`; though which release/ISO/version you are using does influence what options are available and how presented. You haven't said which release, which version (server, desktop, alternate ...) etc.  https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/ch05s01.html  (I've assumed amd64)

Comment: @guiverc Would you be willing to post that (or something like it) as an answer?

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/838450/how-can-ubiquity-be-forced-not-to-install-grub/838527#838527 you can install without grub with just `sudo ubiquity -b` from live installer in live mode.

Comment: That's helpful. Yes its amd64, installing the plain 19.04 desktop. That link does have some suggestions such as installing the bootloader in a different location I think I'll try putting it on the same partition as Ubuntu, that will be handy if I have to cut and paste grub configs for booting Ubuntu into the other grub.cfg. If that doesn't work I'll try Lubuntu.

Comment: code ubiquity --no-bootloader
Worked. No bootloader pull down menu was offered, and it didn't install a bootloader anywhere. Posting this from the new install now.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is available in many forms (including flavors), and does include ISOs that use as the main installer

- Ubiquity
- Calamares
- Subiquity

and more (eg. netboot), but which release you are using, plus ISO you download will dictate which installer is included. Most common is Ubiquity, however as you mention Calamares; it's used by Lubuntu since 18.10. You didn't specify a release or ISO tried.

Ubuntu can also install

- using `grub`
- using `lilo`
- without boot loader

but your architecture also influences the best option for you. You specified neither release nor architecture, so I'll assume amd64 & provide a link to one of the installation guides (*there are many such guides to, suited for different needs*)

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/