# ubiquity installer fails to install grub to correct path

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, ubiquity

am I missing something or why can't grub always be installed where it is directed to with manual partitioning + preseed?

I use a preseed file for xubuntu 20.04.2 desktop that is devoid of partitioning directives. when "automatic-ubiquity" is booted, after manually partitioning sda selecting /dev/sda1 is ignored and grub is installed into /dev/sda.

added `d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean false` and/or `d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean false` to preseed.  after manually partitioning sda selecting /dev/sda1 is ignored and grub is installed into /dev/sda.

I hacked a way to dynamically set `d-i grub-installer/bootdev string default` but that requires booting into the live environment, partitioning the disk and setting the active partition first, then starting "ubiquity -‑automatic" or rebooting with "automatic-ubiquity".

```
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean false
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean false
d-i grub-installer/bootdev string default
d-i partman/early_command string                                               \
 BOOTFLAG=$(lsblk -rpo PARTFLAGS,PKNAME,PATH | grep "0x80" | cut -f 3 -d ' '); \
 if [ $BOOTFLAG ]; then debconf-set grub-installer/bootdev $BOOTFLAG; fi;
```

testing this works with a vm with a single disk, but may not work as desired on hardware with multiple disks or installing from usb.

`d-i grub-installer/skip boolean true` seems ignored always.  again I hacked a way to make that work, I set `d-i grub-installer/bootdev string`  leaving it empty.  manually installing grub in ubiquity/success_command does not work though.  inspecting the first few sectors of /dev/sda1, all are 00.  the other command completes sucessfully.

```
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean false
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean false
d-i grub-installer/bootdev string 
ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string                                       \
 in-target grub-install -‑force /dev/sda1;                                     \
 echo "tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0" >> /target/etc/fstab;
```

Comment: Grub's MBR goes to a device (sda) and **not** a partition (sda1).  The first 512 bytes of the drive (outside of partitioning space) has been reserved for the MBR since ~1981 and machines won't boot if it's on a partition (using legacy/BIOS standard)

Comment: riiight.  I should have made it more clear that the reason I want to install to the partition is because I use a alternate boot loader.  also, while not recommended, grub CAN be installed to the partition and chainloaded from said alternate boot loader.

Comment: If using another boot loader you may not even need to install grub. `sudo ubiquity -b`
http://askubuntu.com/questions/838450/how-can-ubiquity-be-forced-not-to-install-grub/838527#838527

Answer (score 0):

eventually I dropped the `partman/early_command` method.  currently I set `grub-installer/bootdev` to empty and the use `ubiquity/success_command` to force install grub to the `/target` partition and mark it active.

kind of ugly, but it works.  tested for sata/nvme/mbr partition table only and separate boot/home/root partitions with ext2/3/4.

```
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean false
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean false
d-i grub-installer/bootdev string 
ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string                                   \
 echo 'tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0' >> /target/etc/fstab            ;\
 worker() { grub-install --force --root-directory=/target $2             &&\
 parted -s $3 -- set ${4##*-} boot on; }                                  ;\
 worker $(lsblk -lpo MOUNTPOINT,KNAME,PKNAME,PARTUUID | grep '/target ');
```

ultimately I think ubiquity needs to be updated to reflect the selections in the gui.