# How to customize Ubuntu ISO grub install params

Tags: 20.04, grub-efi

I want to customize the installer in default ubuntu 20.04 iso image.

More specifically I want to either

1. Completely skip grub install ( I want to do it manually )
2. Add additional params to grub install command (like --noefivars etc)

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop ISO

Comment: You mention Ubuntu 20.04 ISO image; but have also tagged Lubuntu.  You've not said which installer you plan on using though, as what you provided allows for the use of `ubiquity`, `subiquity` & `calamares`  but haven't been specific as to which you plan on using. There are differences between them (ie. passing the installer messages during the boot process and whether or not the installer actually looks for such messages)

Comment: I am open to suggestions. Lubuntu or Ubuntu , either is fine . Whatever is the default installer of the distro, I'll take it.

Comment: USB's made with Rufus, UNetbootin and mkusb have modifiable GRUB. A USB made with Etcher and Win32DiskImager does not. Rufus and Unetbootin use Syslinux, (txt.cfg), when booting in BIOS mode and GRUB when booting in UEFI mode. mkusb uses grub.cfg for booting either mode. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb. You need to boot from a second Linux USB to edit grub.cfg.

Comment: If you do not want grub installed from live installer:
`sudo ubiquity -b` See also: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/838450/how-can-ubiquity-be-forced-not-to-install-grub/838527#838527  I run a script to modify grub parameters after install & update it.

Comment: Ubuntu has ISOs for *focal* that use `ubiquity` & `subiquity`, Lubuntu & *flavors* use either `ubiquity` or `calamares` so the installer varies on what Ubuntu 20.04 ISO you're talking about. You've not been specific (Ubuntu desktop installs use `ubiquity`, `server` uses `subiquity` & non-KDE *flavors* using Qt5 use `calamares`)

Comment: @guiverc I have narrowed it down to 'Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop ISO' . I didn't know there were so many differences.