# How can I install Ubuntu 22.04 server without installing grub?

Tags: server, grub2

I have an already partition disked with grub installed and configured.  I manually maintain the configuration.

I need to install Ubuntu 22.04 server but can find no option to not install grub.  The installation wipes out my hand crafted grub configuration.

So how can I get it to not install grub?

Comment: the older Ubiquity installer had `sudo ubiquity -b` from live mode's terminal. But server & newest desktops now use Subiquity. Do not know if equivalent works or not. https://askubuntu.com/questions/838450/how-can-ubiquity-be-forced-not-to-install-grub/838527#838527 Other alternative was to install grub to someplace where it would not be used. They may now have prevented grub BIOS install to partition boot sector. If UEFI you could create a new tiny ESP with boot,esp flags, and install grub to that. Then restore current ESP's boot,esp flags and delete extra UEFI boot entry.